# How can I access all files and folders in drive using OneDrive API?

Tags: onedrive, drive, graph-explorer

I want to get a list of all files and folders in the drive with a single request.

I provide this with a recursive function as follows, but as the number of files increases, it becomes impossible to use.

```php
public function listDriveItemsRecursively($graph, $parentItemId)
    {
        $response = $graph->createRequest('GET', '/me/drive/items/' . $parentItemId . '/children')
        ->setReturnType(Model\DriveItem::class)
        ->execute();

        $itemsObj = [];
        foreach ($response as $item) {
            $itemsObj[] = $item->getProperties();
        }

        $allItems = [];
        foreach ($itemsObj as $item) {
            if ($item['folder'] ?? null !== null) {
                $allItems[] = $item;
                $allItems = array_merge($allItems, $this->listDriveItemsRecursively($graph, $item['id']));
            } else {
                $allItems[] = $item;
            }
        }

        return $allItems;
    }
```

Anyone have a suggestion? Have a nice day.